# Migrate files from SP On-prem to file share without modifying created or modified date

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

Is there a way to migrate the contents of a document library to a file share without modifying the 'created by' or 'modified' date? We use ShareGate but it looks like it does changes those fields. The SharePoint migration tool seems to only work when moving to SPO.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of an existing tool, but with a help of PowerShell, you can copy files from SharePoint to file share, then set the timestamps:

```
$file = Get-Item C:\Path\TO\File.txt
$file.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)
$file.CreationTime = (Get-Date)
```

Another option is to copy the files via Windows Explorer and write a simple script that only enumerates the files in SharePoint and sets the timestamps on file share files accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Jussi, I was able to incorporate this on my script and got it working.